# Enumerated list with repeating triplet of numbers and letters

Tags: enumerate, enumitem

I would like to make a list that looks like this

```
1A
1B
1C
2A
2B
2C
...
```

and so on. I've tried the `enumitem` package, but can't seem to make the numbers and letters repeat.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\theenumi\Alph*}]
    \item
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item This is one
        \item This is two
    \end{enumerate}
    \item 
    \item 
    \item 
    \item 
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't use `\bf`... it's deprecated. Use `\textbf{\theenumi\Alph*}` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\theenumi}{%
\@arabic{\numexpr(\value{enumi}+1)/3\relax}%
\@Alph{\numexpr3+\value{enumi}-((\value{enumi}+1)/3)*3\relax}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item
    \item 
    \item 
    \item 
    \item 
    \item 
    \item 
    \item 
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one method

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,chngcntr}
\newcounter{test}
\counterwithin{enumi}{test}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\thetest\Alph*}]
\stepcounter{test}
    \item
    \item 
\stepcounter{test}
    \item 
    \item 
    \item 
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

In your example, `\theenumi` also refers to the outer counter, so the attempt fails. In this example we create a new independent counter `test`, and make sure `enumi` is reset every time `test` is stepped up.